# Can not get source code from ClearCase via TeamCity

Tags: teamcity, clearcase

I used TeamCity to create CI, The CVS is ClearCase. I have test the connection when configure the Version Control Settings on TeamCity, Connection successful!
But when I run this build, it's not correct, the status of build will show "Checking for changes" for a long time, the source code is only 40M.

My ClearCase view's config spec as following:

```
element * CHECKOUT
element * /main/LATEST
load \Tranning
```

Anyone meets the same issue?
Is this configuration correct?

Comment: Don't hesitate to edit your question to add more details, regarding any error messages you could see during that "Checking for changes" step.

Answer (score 0):

The page on "[ClearCase support](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/using-clearcase-integration.html)" mentions:

> When using the ClearCase integration, it is helpful to open the [Version Control tool window](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/version-control-tool-window.html). Its [Console tab](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/console-tab.html) displays the following data:
>
> - All the commands generated based on the settings you specify through the IntelliJ IDEA user interface.
> - Information messages concerning the results of executing generated ClearCase commands.
> - Error messages.

So that would go a long way in order to debug whatever error the integration with ClearCase currently has with your view.

I assume you have the full ClearCase client installed with your agent (not CCRC, ClearCase Remote Control)